# jQuery variable selector not working with find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to pass a unique ID as a variable and having trouble.

```
<span id="e-tt1_1" class="tt1">Trigger 3</span>
<span id="e-tt1_2" class="tt1">Trigger 3</span>
<span id="e-tt1_3" class="tt1">Trigger 3</span>
```

I'm trying to pass a unique ID in a variable to a parsedHTML Ajax response in a newly created DIV and although my console log indicates the selector arrives it doesn't complete the function. I know I'm doing something basic wrong (possibly context) as when the ID is placed directly in the code (see blanked-out-code above "var elements"), it shows the relevant DIV?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.tt1[id^="e-tt1_"]').each(function() {           
    var $scoop = $('#data_' + $(this).attr('id'));
     $(this).qtip({ 
        content: { 
            text: function(event, api) {                        
                    api.elements.content.html('Loading...');

                    return $.ajax({                                 
                        url: 'pages/tooltip-pricing-essential1.html',
                        dataType: 'html'                             
                        })
                        .then(function(content) {                                   
                            // Append the parsed HTML of the retrieved page to a dummy <div/>, and find all <$scoop> elements
                            //var elements = $("<div />").append( $.parseHTML(content) ).find('#data_e-tt1_2');

                            var elements = $("<div />").append( $.parseHTML(content) ).find($scoop);

                            console.log($scoop);                                    

                            // Set the content of the tooltip to the selected element(s)
                            api.set('content.text', elements);

                        }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                                api.set('content.text', status + ':  ' + error);
                    });
                }
        },
        position: {
            target: 'event', // Use the triggering element as the positioning target
            my: 'bottom center',
            at: 'right center',
            adjust: { x: -15 },
            viewport: $(window)
        },
        style: { classes: 'qtip-light qtip-rounded qtip-shadow' },
        hide: {
         fixed: true,
         delay: 1500
        }
     });
 });
 });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why `$('.tt1[id^="e-tt1_"]')` and not `$('.tt1')` ? i don't get it

Comment: Sorry, yes, that is a bit irrelevant but the problem is still the same?

Comment: why do you write `then` instead of `done` ? for the jQuery AJAX deferred? very odd.

Comment: Not sure why but `done` results in the whole page showing and `then` appears to allow individual DIVs to be selected, I may be wrong but it works. It's just the passed variable `$scoop` won't select the DIV but if I place the identical id into `find()` it does. The code works, but the variable doesn't for some reason?

Comment: please do **not** use `then` but use `done` unless you know exactly what it's for (not for that, but for invoking a new promise/deferred). I also don't understand what does it mean "*it doesn't complete the function*".. please specify in exactly which way it doesn't work, and you are expecting and what line is causing the problem.

Comment: As I explained `done` will not "somehow" to get an individual div from the `find` function. If I utilize the code blanked out, which directly puts the DIV id in, the code works. If I use `done` the code only shows the whole page. Using `then` shows the div. The problem is that although my console.log shows the correct identifier, it doesn't get passed properly to the `find` part, I know not why?

Comment: can you build a working demo page please on jsbin or jsfiddle?

Comment: I will but will have to be tomorrow now(late here in France), will post when I have don so, many, many thanks for your time so far vsync...

Comment: I want to help and helping makes me happy :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Nooneo/14hv45ua/ - Finally got a fiddle going, not too clever with the ajax stuff. This example does not work but swap the line `var elements` for the direct div id and the thing works? I can't work out why the variable isn't being passed to `find` when the console.log says it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### https://jsfiddle.net/14hv45ua/53/

```
$('.tt1').each(function() {
  var $scoop = '#data_' + this.id; // <-- this MUST be a "string"
  
  $(this).qtip({
    content: {
      text: function(event, api) {
        api.elements.content.html('Loading...');

        fetchTtip("pages/tooltip-pricing-essential1.html") // <-- see below
          .done(function(content) { // <-- PLEASE use "done" method
            // Append the parsed HTML of the retrieved page to a dummy <div/>, and find all <$scoop> elements
            var element = $("<div>").html(content).find($scoop);
   
            // Set the content of the tooltip to the selected element(s)
            api.set('content.text', element.html()); // <-- value MUST be a "string"
            //api.elements.content.html(content);
          })
          .fail(function(xhr, status, error) { // <-- PLEASE use "fail" method
            api.set('content.text', status + ':  ' + error);
          });
      }
    },
    position: {
      target  : 'event', // Use the triggering element as the positioning target
      my      : 'bottom center',
      at      : 'right center',
      viewport: $(window),
      adjust : {
        x: -15
      }
    },
    style: {
      classes: 'qtip-light qtip-rounded qtip-shadow'
    },
    hide: {
      fixed: true,
      delay: 1500
    }
  });
});

function fetchTtip(URL){
  //// TEMPORARY FOR THIS DEMO - (simulate AJAX) ///////
  var deferred = new $.Deferred(),
      mockData = `
      <div id="data_e-tt1_1"><strong>Title 1</strong><br>text 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit</div>
      <div id="data_e-tt1_2"><strong>Title 2</strong><br>text 2 - aaaa</div>
      <div id="data_e-tt1_3"><strong>Title 3</strong><br>text 3 - bbb bbb</div>`;

  setTimeout(()=>{
    deferred.resolve(mockData);
  }, 1000)

  return deferred;
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////


  return $.ajax({
    url      : URL,
    dataType : 'html'
  })
}
```

Note in the Qtip API, the [`.set()`](http://qtip2.com/api#api-methods.set) method needs `text` value to be passed to it.

---

This is a very very bizarre way and I recommend not fetching tooltip texts from the server, or at least fetch them well before you need to show them.

Also, please do not use a chunk of HTML in the AJAX response but use JSON instead, which is much easier to work with.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this, it works perfectly, you are a gentleman (methinks) and obviously a scholar, and I've managed to learn a few things too. Thanks for all the help and especially the advice, Nooneo

Comment: @Nooneo - happy to help and even more happy that you've learned a few things in the process! it would be *nice* to have this question marked as the correct answer :)

Comment: Bit new to this, not sure if I've done all that's required to mark as correct now?